# Yet a conjecture about the prime counting function.

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, conjectures

This is a conjecture emanating from random tests with my set routines written in Forth.

> $a>b \;\wedge \pi(a+b)=\pi(a)+\pi(b)\implies b<11$
>
> Furthermore, if $b\in\mathbb N$, then $b\in\{0,1,2,3,4,9,10 \}$

I would like (partly) proofs or counterexamples.

Tested for $b<a<100,000$.

Testing the numbers of hits for the non trivial values of $b$ and for some upper limits:

```
               1       2       3       4       9      10
    100       74      48       8      14       2       2
   1000      832     332      34      66       4       6
  10000     8771    2454     204     406      11      20
 100000    90408   19180    1223    2444      37      72
1000000   921502  156992    8168   16334     165     328
```

Answer (score 3):

Your claim is a consequence of the [Secondly Hardy Littlewood conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_Hardy%E2%80%93Littlewood_conjecture) which has been open since 1923. We don't even know if $\pi(a+b) \le \pi(a) + \pi(b)$ holds in general so proving $\pi(a+b) = \pi(a) + \pi(b)$ implies $b < 11$ is beyond the current state of art.

Comment: I can't see that the the openness of the inequality influence of my conjecture. But thanks for the link!

Comment: @Lehs If there are large $a, b$ with $\pi(a+b)\gt \pi(a)+\pi(b)$ — that is, if the conjecture _doesn't_ hold — then by increasing $b$ monotonically we can get a $b_0\gt b$ with $\pi(a+b_0)=\pi(a)+\pi(b_0)$. (This is because of the asymptotics of the counting function along with the fact that if $f(a,b)=\pi(a+b)-\pi(a)-\pi(b)$, then $|f(a,b+1)-f(a,b)|\leq 1$). So your conjecture would, in turn, imply the Hardy-Littlewood conjecture.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki - But my conjecture isn't about large numbers $b$. And it doesn't predict an equality.